# Merge Not Working Properly in Python, Duplicating Columns

Tags: python

I have this dataframe called MergeAttendance:

```
                          OverallAtt201819  OverallAttCurrent
students                                                     
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8415         98.670213          93.333333
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8416         97.340426          98.360656
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8417         98.936170          95.000000
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8418         98.936170          97.540984
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8419         98.404255          97.540984
```

I also have another dataframe called ThisYearSess:

```
students
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8415    22400.0
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8416    24000.0
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8417    22800.0
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8418    23800.0
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8419    23800.0
```

However, when I try to merge both dataframes together based on the students, it recreates the student column, instead of merging it. This is my code:

```
MergeAttendance2 = pd.merge(MergeAttendance, ThisYearSess, on='students')
```

This is what it produces:

```
                          OverallAtt201819  OverallAttCurrent  \
students                                                        
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8415         98.670213          93.333333   
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8416         97.340426          98.360656   
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8417         98.936170          95.000000   
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8418         98.936170          97.540984   
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8419         98.404255          97.540984   

                          OverallSessionsAttendedSoFar  
students                                                
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8415                       22400.0  
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8416                       24000.0  
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8417                       22800.0  
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8418                       23800.0  
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8419                       23800.0
```

How can I stop it adding in the student column again?

Comment: What is the desired output ?

Comment: Hmm..., I suspect a display problem. What is the result of `MergeAttendance2 .columns`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC: and `students` column is set as your `index` of both the dataframes then you can try this:

```
MergeAttendance2 = MergeAttendance.merge(ThisYearSess, left_index=True, right_index=True, how="outer")
print(MergeAttendance2)
```

**Output:**

```
                         OverallAtt201819  OverallAttCurrent  OverallSessionsAttendedSoFar
students                                                                                   
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8415         98.670213          93.333333                       22400.0
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8416         97.340426          98.360656                       24000.0
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8417         98.936170          95.000000                       22800.0
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8418         98.936170          97.540984                       23800.0
5bf3e06e9a892068705d8419         98.404255          97.540984                       23800.0
```